# How to pass method into function outside the Class?

Tags: python

I might be missing something stupid, or I am simply trying to *walk through a steel wall instead of going around*. Basically I have created `turtle` class and I use it in different script for drawing L-systems. I thought I could create a function **outside the** `turtle` **class**, which will accept:

- `turtle` - the instance of from my `turtle` class
- a string from L-system
- dictionary of rules/instructions of how to interpret different symbols in the string above,  that is for which symbol call which method from the `turtle` class

But it all crashes on trying to pass the method to the function - I think it does not see the method, since it is defined inside the class. To simplify the matters I have created a basic example, which fails at the same place:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age


    def birthday(self):
        self.age += 1

def foo(person, method):

    person.method()

jane = Person(20)
foo(jane, birthday)

#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "passmethod.py", line 14, in <module>
#    foo(jane, birthday)
#NameError: name 'birthday' is not defined
```

That is:

- the only variable in `Person` class instance is `age`, the only method `birthday` raises the age by 1.
- `jane` is `Person` class instance, initialized at 20 years old
- the by function `foo` I am trying to call `birthday` method on her
- script does not see `birthday` method and crashes

**So, my question(s) is(are)**:

- Is there a way, how to do it? If so, how?
- If not or if it would not be advisable to do so, what should I use?

#### Update

Thanks for those quick and nice answers! The additional question which naturally follows - is any of those ways preferred? I would guess, that

- `__getattribute__` and `getattr` are pretty much the same, although for the first one, the inheritance is probably necessary.
- I don't see any great difference *in this case* between using `jane.birthday` or `Person.birthday`, although in general it could be useful to be able to call the method for different `Person` instances, e.g. created in the `foo` function.

Comment: Pass a string for method name and use `getattr()`.

Comment: You can also pass method objects around directly. `jane.birthday` is a callable object representing `jane`'s `birthday` method, and you can stick that in a dict and call it without knowing the name of the method or what object's method it is.

Comment: Why don't you build that method and the `rules` (as a *class attribute*?) right into the `Turtle`, then just call e.g. `turtle.follow_instructions(instructions)`?

Comment: user2357112, 200OK(sadly I can notify only one of you) Thanks, both ways works nicely! @jonrsharpe It might be a good way, but since it is a school project, where I present every script as a part of my work, I think it would be more readable to have smaller scripts. This way everything is compact, and after quick view, you know, what it does and to which particular task it relates.

Comment: @quapka you could always have a separate sub-class (e.g. `class InstructableTurtle(Turtle)`) that inherits the basic functionality from `Turtle` and implements the additional `follow_instructions` - this would allow you to split the basic functions and the rule-following across two classes or even files.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did not used inheritance before, so I did not see that way. In fact, I might as well try it, since learning something new should not hurt!

Comment: On your update: you can only choose a preferred method depending on the problem you're solving. (By the way, you can extract unbound method from bound method: `unbound = bound.im_func`. Just in case :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Here the working code:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age


    def birthday(self):
        self.age += 1

def foo(person, method):

    getattr(person, method)()
```

Test:

```
>>> 
>>> jane = Person(20)
>>> foo(jane, 'birthday')
>>> jane.age
21
>>>
```

Comment: This, use inbuilts rather than directly using "magic" methods

Comment: @ChrisClarke, if want using "magic" method, change:
getattr(person, method)() to method()  and
access by: foo(jane, jane.birthday)
the result will be same.

Comment: You misunderstand, I was suggesting this method was better than person._getattribute__(method)

Comment: @ChrisClarke, i'm so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are ways to do that.

First way: just pass method bound to a particular object:

```
def foo(person, method):
    method() # calls jane.birthday()

jane = Person(20)
foo(jane, jane.birthday)
```

Second way: pass a class method and apply it to a particular object:

```
def foo(person, method):
    method(person) # calls Person.birthday(jane), which is the same thing

jane = Person(20)
foo(jane, Person.birthday)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `__getattribute__` method (inherited from `object`):

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, age):
        self.age = age

    def birthday(self):
        self.age += 1

def foo(person, method):
    person.__getattribute__(method)()

jane = Person(20)
foo(jane, "birthday")
```

Comment: Why not the builtin `getattr()`? `__getattribute__()` might not handle all cases...

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comments, you could sub-class your `Turtle` to add a rule-following method. To demonstrate a trivial example:

```
class InstructableTurtle(Turtle):

    def follow_instructions(self, instructions):
        for instruction in instructions:
            if instruction == "MOVE_LEFT":
                self.move_left()
            ...
```

But you could also have the `rules` provided as an additional argument to the new instance:

```
def __init__(self, ..., rules): # '...' represents args to base Turtle 
    super().__init__(...) # or 'super(InstructableTurtle, self)' on Python 2.x
    self.rules = rules
```

As an example:

```
>>> class Turtle():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def move_left(self):
        print("{0.name} is moving left...".format(self))


>>> class InstructableTurtle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, name, rules):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.rules = rules
    def follow_instruction(self, instruction):
        self.rules[instruction](self)


>>> tommy = InstructableTurtle("Tommy", {"LEFT": Turtle.move_left})
>>> tommy.follow_instruction("LEFT")
Tommy is moving left...
```